# RGB EPS figures appear as CMYK in LaTeX

Tags: color, diagrams

When I make EPS figures in Matlab and/or Illustrator, they look RGB, however, in the DVI file and in the subsequent PDF or PS file it appears CMYK.  When I open up the figures outside of LaTeX, they look the way they should.  How do I fix this (i.e. make my figures appear in RGB)?

Comment: Could you upload your EPS file for us?

Comment: Without the EPS file concerned and some idea of the TeX code used, we really can't hope to answer.